# ZfcUser add additional checks at login

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I have an active and inactive users. How do I add a check to authorize only those who have `is_active = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the login event, and redirect the user if it's not active.
This is an example of how to use an event: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-perform-a-custom-action-when-a-new-user-account-is-created

Comment: For a good answer, it's better to extract somes code, or explaination, event if it's copy pasted. If your link is not available in the future, you answer still relevant.